# How do I configure Jenkins to Git on Assembla?

Tags: git, jenkins, build-automation

I was able to clone Git via ToutoiseGit (used RSA public key) however not able to clone via Jenkins or bash. Can some one help me whether I have to tweak some setting in Jenkins. The error I got in bash is
"Permission denied(publickey, keyboard-interactive)
fatal: could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Jenkins needs a key pair to authenticate with:

```
sudo su - -s /bin/bash jenkins
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "jenkins@aws"
```

In your Assembla settings you need to share that secret.
Then, connect with git (over ssh) using the shell the first time to get rid of the "press yes" annoyance.

`git ls-remote -h git@git.assembla.com:projectname.git HEAD`

After that Jenkins should cope.

[I wrote it all down](http://splashinapond.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/ci-with-jenkins-ant-git-and-assembla.html) in a bit more detail to help me remember!

Comment: I had to setup git with my name/email before generating the key but when I followed the instructions in Assembla (Instructions tab when repo selected) it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the jenkins user is a daemon with limited access. You might have to change the user configuration so that it is not a daemon. See this link below. http://colonelpanic.net/2011/06/jenkins-on-mac-os-x-git-w-ssh-public-key/